# GPIOD on Raspberry Pi 3b+ not found

Tags: c, gcc, raspberry-pi, gpio, libgpiod

I installed the GPIOD library for c on my Raspberry Pi 3b+ using `sudo apt-get install gpiod` which finished successfully.
I can find the respective files in */usr/lib* etc.
Also I can execute `gpioinfo`.

In my program I `#inlcude <gpiod.h>` but when compiling with GCC using `gcc -lgpiod -o btn button.c`, I get an error stating *gpiod.h* was not found after which the comilation is stopped.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the `libgpiod-dev` package, which provides header files and libraries for linking.

It is very common to split packages between "things that provide user facing commands" and "things that are required for development". The latter generally have a `-dev` suffix.

---

```
root@rpi:~# apt install libgpiod-dev
.
.
.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libgpiod-dev
.
.
.
root@rpi:~# dpkg -L libgpiod-dev
/.
/usr
/usr/include
/usr/include/gpiod.h
/usr/include/gpiod.hpp
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgpiod.a
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgpiodcxx.a
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkgconfig
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkgconfig/libgpiod.pc
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkgconfig/libgpiodcxx.pc
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libgpiod-dev
/usr/share/doc/libgpiod-dev/README.gz
/usr/share/doc/libgpiod-dev/changelog.Debian.armhf.gz
/usr/share/doc/libgpiod-dev/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libgpiod-dev/copyright
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgpiod.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgpiodcxx.so
```

---

To link against `libgpiod` (or any other library), you need to ensure that any library references come *after* your source files (symbols are resolved from left to right):

```
gcc -o btn button.c -lgpiod
```

For example, if I have in `example.c`:

```
#include <gpiod.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  const char *chipname = "gpiochip0";
  struct gpiod_chip *chip;

  // Open GPIO chip
  chip = gpiod_chip_open_by_name(chipname);

  gpiod_chip_close(chip);
  return 0;
}
```

This fails:

```
root@rpi:~# gcc -lgpiod  -o example example.c
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc30WQLG.o: in function `main':
example.c:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `gpiod_chip_open_by_name'
/usr/bin/ld: example.c:(.text+0x2c): undefined reference to `gpiod_chip_close'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But this works:

```
root@rpi:~# gcc -o example example.c -lgpiod
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked out so far. Now I got a new problem, the #include works, but the commands like gpiod_chip_open are not found (unknown reference)
I had this with wiringPi, too.
Do you know how to fix this one, too?

Comment: See my update to the answer.

Comment: Big thanks again, I did not think this has any effect. I did it the other way around for 2 years now (without knowing much about the background) and it always worked.
I will remember it from now on and thanks a lot :)